# Same audio/video playback for everyone over http

Tags: asp.net, .net, web, video-streaming

I would like to playback the same audio/video to everyone who lands on a page. So I will have video X playing centrally and whoever joins the site will continue watching the video from whatever playback time the video is in and NOT from the beginning. This way when the video finishes playback the new video will start playback for everyone who happens to be on the page.

Any .Net solution will be preferable I am also open to different technologies. audio/video format is not relevant as I can convert between different types.

Thank you in advance for any answers.

Comment: You need to have a SERVER for this. Windows Media Services (in case you dealing with microsoft platform). you can use .NET to communicate with media services.

Comment: Simple RTSP can do this, but that ain't http!

Comment: @av501, thanks for the suggestion, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Well, RTSP is primarily for realtime streaming, once a session has been started, as others join in they can get from the current streaming point or from the begining. Look at Darwin/ Live555 server. They are servers you can use. There are plenty of others too.

Comment: Windows Media Server provides RTSP support, you would still need a media server...see a list here: http://www.flashrealtime.com/list-of-available-rtmp-servers/

Comment: @av501 and highwingers. Thank you both, I think I know where to start.